# QThread object won't emit `finished` signal if add `return super().run()` at the end of `run()`

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

## Question

I find a issue in `QThread`, if you use `super().run()` in your `QThread` obj, it will not emit the finished signal. And, I find the definition of `QThread.run()`, it is no different. So I want to ask why it happened.(I create a test for `threading.Thread`, it is normal).

## Screenshot

The definition of `QThread.run()`
[image]

## Code

### threading.Thread Code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading


class InThreading(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(InThreading, self).__init__()

    def run(self) -> None:
        print('threading thread')
        print(threading.enumerate())
        return super().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inthreadng = InThreading()
    print(threading.enumerate())
    inthreadng.start()
    inthreadng.join()
    print(threading.enumerate())
```

### QThread Code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class User_Interface(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(User_Interface, self).__init__()
        self.usage()

    def usage(self):
        qtthread = QtThread(self)
        qtthread.start()
        qtthread.finished.connect(lambda: print('qtthrediing finished!'))


class QtThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QtThread, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def run(self) -> None:
        print('created QThread Example')
        return super().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = User_Interface()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As the documentation [explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run), "The default implementation simply calls exec().", which, [in turn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec), "Enters the event loop and **waits until exit() is called**". It doesn't emit `finished` because it *has not finished*, it's just running its own event loop. `finished` is emitted only when `run()` returns, and since you've never called `exit()`, `run()` doesn't return.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this, if add `qtthread.exit()` after `qtthread.start()`, I can get the desired result.